# How can we ensure reliable and low-latency kafka writing using confluent-kafka-go client?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

The sample producer code at https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go calls `Producer.Produce(...)`  It writes the message to the sending buffer queue and return immediately. However, writing to the internal buffer queue does not guarantee successful message delivery. How can we ensure sucessful message delivery here?

```
for idx, word := range []string{"Welcome", "to", "the", 
                                "Confluent", "Kafka", "Golang", "client"} {
    start_time := time.Now().UnixNano()
    p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
        TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, 
                                             Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
        Value:          []byte(word),
    }, nil)
}
```

Comment: may be this can help : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs_acks

Answer (score 1):

To block and send data immediately, you'd call Flush method of the producer

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/producer.go#L335

To ensure it's written reliably, set acks=all producer config and ensure the topic is configured to have min in sync replicas as 2 or more, and topic replication factor as 3 or more